# Kotlin - lambda to return list of member variables

Tags: kotlin

Preface: This is something I'm not sure Kotlin can do, but I feel like it should be able to do.

Question: **Is it possible to return a list composed from another lists' member variables without creating a separate function, via lambda, mapping, or otherwise?**

I have a Kotlin inner class that has a name string representing a physical COM port.  I have a routine that will poll for available COM ports on a device, and will return a list of the available port name strings for selection.

```
inner class ComPort() {

val portName: String = "something"

... }

...


ComPortSelectBox.setItems(*getComPortNames())

...

private fun getComPortNames(): Array<String> {
  val names: ArrayList<String> = ArrayList()

  for(comPort in availableComPorts)
    { names + comPort.portName }

  return names.toTypedArray()
}
```

Because `getComPortNames()` is only used in the one location, I would love to simplify this call into something equivalent to `getComPortNames` that I can use inline within `.setItems(...)`.  Is this possible within Kotlin? If so, how would one do it?

Comment: Assuming availableComPorts is a List<ComPort>, you simply want availableComPorts.map(ComPort::portName).toTypedArray(), is that what you're asking?

Comment: That is what I'm asking, correct. And that solution does work!  Funnily enough I was close on an attempt I had but my syntax was slightly wrong. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure what `availableComPorts` actually is, but it looks like `Iterable`. If so then you may do something like:

```
ComPortSelectBox.setItems(*availableComPorts.map(ComPort::portName).toTypedArray())
```

UPD. You did't mention which Java you're using. I assumed it is Java 8.

Comment: That works, thank you very much! The ```ComPort::portName``` is what tripped me up on a previous attempt, so thank you very much for the clarification.

Comment: You're welcome! Lambda syntax in Kotlin look quite similar to ones in Java if you're familiar with it. Anyway official [doc](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html) might be helpful.